# What's the difference among bandwidth, ping, ping rate and latency?

Tags: bandwidth, ping, latency

All these terms are quite related but I couldn't understand when to use which. I often hear that some networks have low bandwidth and high ping rate for online gaming. I thought they might be inversely proportional but that's not the case. When someone introduces "high ping and low ping" it becomes more confusing. What are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ping is a utility to test network connectivity. It uses ICMP echo request/reply to do this. The originating host sends an ICMP echo request, and the receiving host sends an ICMP echo reply. There are several messages which may be returned:

- The target host could reply, and you have a successful ping.
- If a certain time period passes before receiving a message, you get a
  timeout. This is caused by the host on a different network not
  replying (firewall, target down, unidirectional routing, etc.) during
  the allotted time period.
- You could get a destination unreachable message, meaning that the
  layer-3 address could not be resolved to the layer-2 address. This
  implies that either the host is on the same network, and it did not
  respond to ARP, or if the host is on a different network, the
  configured gateway for your host is down or misconfigured.
- You could get a network unreachable message, meaning the host is on a
  different network, and a router in the path has no route to the
  network for the target host.

Most ping programs run the ping several times, and they return a round-trip ICMP network latency. The Ping program usually gives you the number of packets sent, received, lost, and the loss percent, along with the lowest, highest, and average ping latency. Unfortunately, this is often confused with a real network latency, but the two may not be related on a network with multiple hops, especially the Internet where ICMP is often delayed or rerouted, unlike other traffic. ICMP is not the protocol used for most data communications, and the latency returned by ping may not reflect any other application latency.

Bandwidth is only indirectly related to latency. The bandwidth on an unloaded network has nothing at all to do with the latency. The real network latency is due mostly to network congestion, and bandwidth plays the largest part in that for busy networks. Latency reflect the aggregation of distance latency, and the latency added by network devices in the path. The largest component of the latency is by the network devices, due to congestion on the network, and a busy connection causes congestion.

Comment: Suppose I've a network with very high latency..Does it affect bandwidth?

Comment: No. Bandwidth is what it is. If you have high latency, there is network congestion somewhere in the path from the source to the destination, or you are trying to go a very long distance. If your link to or from your ISP is congested, that could cause high latency, but the bandwidth of the link remains the same. The bandwidth is how many bits the link can transfer per second,. If you have multiple streams of data trying to use the same link, it can become congested, receiving more bits per second than its bandwidth (what it can send).

Comment: Case-2: Suppose I've network with high ping rate..does it affect latency and bandwidth or either of them?

Comment: @user334283, the thing about ping (ICMP) latency is that some people want to relate it to how other applications perform, and that is just a fallacy. Your ping latency may not have anything at all to do with how another application performs. ICMP is usually relegated to the lowest priority, and it can end up sitting in queues while other, real traffic is sent through. Some ISPs will route it in a different path than your other traffic, sending it the long way around, or through secondary connections. What ping tells you is that you can connect, not how applications will perform.

Comment: OpenVPN server providers write both bandwidth and ping rate. You can see it here: http://www.vpngate.net/en/ .. Doesn't ping rate have any role if you're using VPN?

Comment: A VPN is just a wrapper packet for your packet. The VPN packet will not be ICMP, but it will contain an ICMP packet. The VPN is not treated the same way as ICMP. This site is not a discussion site, and we have gone will beyond the original question. If you want to discuss this, there is the [chat] for that.

Comment: Ping rate really matters in online gaming. A user with low ping rate will be able to play smoothly. You can read this here: http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1830986/ping.html

Comment: @user334283, that is a myth perpetuated by people who don't understand the difference  between ICMP and other data. ICMP is **_not_** TCP or UDP, which are the protocols most applications use. You could have a high ping latency, but your application has a good latency. People want to relate one to the other, but it is apples and oranges.

Comment: Hello Ron. Thnx for sorting this great misconception. As you see that this misconception is widely spread among people so I want to ask one more thing from you. Does "high ping" mean "high ping rate"? Does more "millisecond" of ping mean high or low? I can't ask this question on Stack chat because I'm sure that misconception will be widely there among users.

Comment: The lower the number of ms, the less latency in the ping. There are tools specifically designed to test latency for TCP or UDP (used for real-time traffic). Search the Internet for something like `test tcp latency`.

Comment: Latency can also be greater when there are more hops and/or a longer path or significantly slow line rate on a link even when there is no congestion. Note that some applications are much more sensitive to latency and others are more sensitive to bandwidth.

Comment: @RonMaupin: Do you have any references to support your assertion that "ICMP is usually relegated to the lowest priority, and it can end up sitting in queues"? Or that "Some ISPs will route it in a different path than your other traffic"? In my experience ISPs don't really do the former (or sometimes do the reverse - to stop gamers complaining about "slow pings"), and the latter hardly ever, if at all. But maybe your experience is with different ISPs :) Do you have any pointers to resources discussing this sort of thing?

Comment: @psmears, have you ever run a traceroute and noticed that many of the intermediate hops have a higher latency than the end-to-end hop? That is due to ICMP being relegated to a low priority. I cannot reveal much about what I know of ISPs due to NDAs, and resource recommendations are off-topic for SE sites. I'm not sure what gamers have to do with pings because ping uses ICMP, and games do not. In any case, some ISPs will reroute ICMP, and some look for low TTL values (traceroute) to reroute. Many do not want casual discovery. Also, it is possible that path can change from one test to another.

Comment: @psmears, I work for a huge company that is bigger than all but the largest ISPs. We have (huge) contracts with many ISPs, and there is always someone who wants to use ping and traceroute to try to verify SLAs. The ISPs have NDAs and explain to us what they are doing. We are privvy to the internal networks of many of the ISPs, and, for some, must give them some of our addressing so that they can make sure our tests reflect reality, as opposed to regular customers.

Comment: @RonMaupin: (1) I'm not asking for resources, I'm suggesting that this answer could be improved by adding some sources to back up the assertions :) (2) No, I've never experienced that--but, as I say, the ISPs I have most experience with don't do that. (Corporate networks are a different matter!) (3) The relevance of gamers is that they often "know" they need a low RTT, so they'll complain to the ISP if they consider their "ping is too high" - regardless of whether they're actually seeing any lag in their games at all. So it's tempting for their ISPs to prioritise ICMP to keep them quiet!

Answer (score 2):

Ping or ping rate, the name of the network diagnostic tool, used to test whether traffic can get through or not. Having a low ping is always desirable because lower latency provides smoother gameplay by allowing faster updates of game data. For more:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(video_gaming)

Latency is the amount of time, it takes a packet to travel from source to destination, which is normally expressed in  milliseconds. While bandwidth is normally expressed in bits per second. It's the amount of data that can be transferred during a second.

In short, bandwidth is a measure of capacity. Latency is a measure of delay.

If you’re downloading huge files, you probably care more about bandwidth than latency. If you’re trying to watch high-definition video, both are equally important. If you’re playing an online game, latency may be far more important than bandwidth.

Comment: Ping measures ICMP latency, and that may not reflect at all the latency by any other application. ICMP is not TCP or UDP, and it is often treated much differently in a network, or even rerouted,, especially the Internet.